# Access, query doesn't work because of special chars

Tags: php, ms-access, encoding

I have small script that is making select to MS Asscess db, query looks like this

```
 $sql  = "SELECT * FROM Employee WHERE EmployeeName LIKE %$user_full_name%";
```

where `$user_full_name` have special characters like óńćżźśąę, if those chars are replaced by `_` query will have result but they are not 100% accurate, so i wanted to use `mb_convert_encoding` to encode my `select query` to that of ms access but all known encodings don't work, is there a way to make ms access understand it, or where i can get info in what encoding is my ms Access?

Comment: Are those characters stored in your access DB as that? If so what encoding are you using? Sounds like via this thread, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5222705/how-to-convert-ms-access-database-encoding-to-utf-8, that access doesnt support utf8.. Oh.. actually reading more that was access 2003 so maybe you have updated...

Comment: i have ms access 2010 driver installed, and i don't know what `access` encoding have i'm using utf-8 in my app

Comment: I'm not sure either but if you have 2 different encodings that could be your issue. I'd start there.

Comment: if i would know encoding in Access this question would be meaningless

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$sql  = "SELECT * FROM Employee WHERE EmployeeName LIKE '*$user_full_name*'";
```

I would also do this:

```
$sql  = "SELECT * FROM Employee WHERE EmployeeName LIKE '*".$user_full_name."*'";
```

but that is just personal preference.